# The Drawing Tools won't show on my map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestMap.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestMap" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8sE5-1UPLAT2UqkNqRiMnvVNh9UNZk-0&callback=initMap">
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    function initMap() {
        var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(41, -103);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: centerPoint,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            keyboardShortcuts: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            drawingControl: true,
            zoom: 8
        };

      //  alert('initMap');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {icon: 'images/pUmjb.jpg'},
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}

 
</script>

    MAP:
    <div style="width:800px; height:500px" id="map"></div>


</asp:Content>
```

I am trying to use v3 of the google maps api, and it's all working fine so far, except that I can't seem to get the toolbar for the drawing tools to show on the map.  Here is the code for a very simplified WebForm.  I'm guessing that I'm just missing one parameter or one line of code somewhere, but I just can't seem to make it work.

Comment: You are including the API twice, that will cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Only include the API one time.  If you want/need to use a key (it is recommended but not required), include it in the parameters of the single include.  The `sensor` parameter is no longer required.

(**update:** keys are now required)

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyB8sE5-1UPLAT2UqkNqRiMnvVNh9UNZk-0&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(41, -103);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: centerPoint,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    keyboardShortcuts: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    drawingControl: true,
    zoom: 8
  };

  //  alert('initMap');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      // icon: 'images/pUmjb.jpg' use default icon
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```